# Can't select element's value loaded by PHP from Database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have enlisted data from database using PHP. I'm unable to select element's value. Although the data is loaded in DOM. If i just write HTML markup then i'm able to select it other

```
<?php
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_code, product_name, product_desc, product_img_name, price FROM products ORDER BY id ASC");
if($results){ 
$products_item = '<ul class="products">';
//fetch results set as object and output HTML
while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
{
$products_item .= <<<EOT
    <li class="product">
    <form method="post" onsubmit="return false">
    <div class="product-content"><h3>{$obj->product_name}</h3>
    <div class="product-thumb"><img src="images/{$obj->product_img_name}"></div>
    <div class="product-desc">{$obj->product_desc}</div>
    <div class="product-info">
    Price {$currency}{$obj->price} 

    <fieldset>

    <label>
        <span>Color</span>
        <select name="product_color" class='product_color'>
        <option value="Black">Black</option>
        <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
        </select>
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Quantity</span>
        <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="product_qty" class='product_qty' id='product_qty' value="1" />
    </label>

    </fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="{$obj->product_code}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="{$current_url}" />
    <div align="center"><button class="add_to_cart" id='add_to_cart' type='submit'>Add</button></div>
    </div></div>
    </form>
    </li>
EOT;
}
$products_item .= '</ul>';
echo $products_item;
}
?>
```

Here's the javascript im using.

```
window.onload = function () {
   $('.add_to_cart').click(function(){

       $parent = $(this).parent();
    $qty = $parent.children('.product-desc').text();
    alert($qty);
   })
};
```

Above code works, if i just use HTML Markup rather using above HTML generated using PHP.

Thanks in advance. Searched a lot for this but didn't find anything relevant. Although i also tried Javascripts '.on' and '.live' function but they didn't worked.

Comment: Sorry it was just pasting mistake. Updated it. That didn't worked either already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$parent = $(this).parent();` selects the `<div align="center">` around the button. Use `$parent = $(this).closest('.product');` instead.

Though I would recommend actually binding to the `submit` event of the form instead of to the `click` of the button.

Comment: It did worked by binding for submit event, Thankyou. But i also want to know if this wasn't a form how would i make it work?

Comment: Don't know how it would work otherwise. I thought my original answer would do the trick. ;-) One other thing I noticed is that your button has got an id attribute. Ids have to be unique. But I don't think it is responsible for your problem.